# Wildfly 27.0.1 serves blank page instead of administration console

Tags: keycloak, wildfly

I think I lost some hair on this one. I'm having a problem with Wildfly - I installed it on a remote server, however, when I try to enter the administration console it gives me a blank page only.

Wildfly version 27.0.1.Final

Problem:

1. I visit MYDOMAIN.XYZ where I should see the administration console
2. I pass the authorization with user details created via ssh
3. I'm redirected to MYDOMAIN.XYZ/console/index.html
4. The loader is briefly visible, but it disappears very soon
5. As a final result this document is served:

```
<!DOCTYPE html\>
<html class="layout-pf layout-pf-fixed" lang="en"\>
<head\>
<title\>HAL Management Console\</title\>
<meta charset="utf-8"\>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"\>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"\>
<link rel="icon shortcut" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.db74b3b0.ico"\>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.fedc4af6.png"\>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dev.291b1e16.css" media="screen"\>
<script type="module" src="dev.75953f7e.js"\>\</script\>\<script src="dev.159a2c8f.js" nomodule defer\>\</script\>\<script src="hal.nocache.js"\>\</script\>
</head\>
<body\> \</body\>
</html\>
```

5. Here's a log from console

```
index.html:1          GET https://MYDOMAIN.XYZ/console/dev.75953f7e.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403
hal-0.js:10337 Set log level to INFO
hal.nocache.js:6 \[Violation\] 'readystatechange' handler took 202ms
hal-0.js:10706          GET https://MYDOMAIN.XYZ/keycloak/adapter/wildfly-console 404
hal-0.js:10713 10:09:20.670 ERROR o.j.h.c.b.endpoint.EndpointManager       Keycloak adapter 'https://MYDOMAIN.XYZ/keycloak/adapter/wildfly-console' doesn't exist - status: 404
hal-0.js:8553          POST https://MYDOMAIN.XYZ/management 403
hal-0.js:10713 10:09:20.730 ERROR o.j.h.d.dispatch.Dispatcher              Dispatcher error: Authentication required.
hal-0.js:10713 10:09:20.730 ERROR o.j.h.c.bootstrap.HalBootstrapper        Bootstrap error: Dispatcher error: Authentication required.
dev.291b1e16.css:1          GET https://MYDOMAIN.XYZ/console/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.b6d3c411.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 403
dev.291b1e16.css:1          GET https://MYDOMAIN.XYZ/console/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.e5de314f.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 403
dev.291b1e16.css:1          GET https://MYDOMAIN.XYZ/console/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.8bd2b33b.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 403
```

6. When I start wildfly several warnings are logged:

```
10:08:17,750 WARN  \[org.jboss.as.warn.fd-limit\] (main) WFLYSRV0071: The operating system has limited the number of open files to 3000 for this process; a value of at least 4096 is recommended 10:08:19,117 WARN  \[org.jboss.as.controller\] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) WFLYCTL0481: The runtime dependency package 'io.smallrye.opentracing-contrib' is already registered at location '/subsystem=microprofile-opentracing-smallrye' 10:08:19,126 WARN  \[org.jboss.as.controller\] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) WFLYCTL0481: The runtime dependency package 'io.smallrye.opentracing-contrib' is already registered at location '/subsystem=microprofile-opentracing-smallrye' 10:08:19,821 WARN  \[org.jboss.as.txn\] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique. 10:08:20,355 WARN  \[org.wildfly.extension.elytron\] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYELY00023: KeyStore file '/home/FOLDER/wildfly/standalone/configuration/application.keystore' does not exist. Used blank. 10:08:20,372 WARN  \[org.wildfly.extension.elytron\] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYELY01084: KeyStore /home/FOLDER/wildfly/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self-signed certificate for host localhost
```

I tried disabling WAF and changing the configuration in `standalone.xml` from:

```
<interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
```

to

```
<interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
```

However, this did not have any effect.

These keycloak errors are suspicious, especially that Wildfly moved to elytrum (from what I read). However, I'm not sure how I should handle them. What can be the problem? Is there something I can do to fix this? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: The log messages in 6) are expected on an initial boot, but is there more context to the errors in 5)? Those are just webpage resources, so they don't reveal why authentication failed.

Comment: I have the same setup and I am experiencing the same issue